Variance of random sum of random variables
Let $N$ be a non-negative integer random variable with mean $\mu_1$ and variance $\sigma_1^2$.$X_1$, $X_2$, .... identically distributed random variables with mean $\mu_2$ and variance $\sigma_2^2$. Let $N$, $X_1$, ... independent. Find variance $S_N=X_1+X_2+...X_N$.
My decision is:
$var(S_N)=\mathbb{E}(S_N-\mathbb{E}S_N)^2=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}[(S_N-\mathbb{E}S_N)^2|N])=\mathbb{E}(N\sigma_2^2)=\mu_1\sigma_2^2$
But the right answer is: $\mu_1\sigma_2^2+\mu_2^2\sigma_1^2$.
I don't understand where in my logic mistake is.

You need parentheses to see your mistake: $E[(S_N-E[S_N])^2|N]$. It is easier if you first compute $E[S_N]$ and then compute $E[S_N^2]$.

But this is not true that $E[(S_N−E[S_N])^2|N]=N\sigma_2^2$?

$E[(S_N-N\mu_2)^2|N]=N\sigma_2^2$

The law of total variance gives $\operatorname{Var}(Y) = \mathbb{E}[\operatorname{Var}(Y \mid X)] + \operatorname{Var}(\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X])$ to reflect the contribution of both sources of dispersion.  You should have been surprised that $\sigma_1^2$ did not appear anywhere in your initial attempt.

ooo, yes, I've understood.  For me this is kind a subtle moment. Thank you! For law of total variance special thanks)
